# modelselection.Kfold gives different results than kf.split

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a dataset [TelcoSigtel](https://www.kaggle.com/sharathchandra4545/telecom-sigtel) which has 5k observations, 21 features, and an imbalanced target with 86% non-churner and 16% churner.

Sorry, I wanted to give an extract of the dataframe but it is way too big or when I try to take a small bunch there are not enough churners.

My problem is the following those two methods below should give the same results but it is dramatically different on some algorithms and on some other they give the exact same results.

Information about the dataset:

```
models = [('logit',
  LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                     intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=600,
                     multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None,
                     solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)), ....]
# Method 1:

from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold


X = telcom.drop("churn", axis=1)
Y = telcom["churn"]

results = []
names = []

seed = 0
scoring = "roc_auc"
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = seed)

    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison-AUC')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Method 2:


from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)

X = telcom.drop("churn", axis=1)
Y = telcom["churn"]

results = []
names = []

to_store1 = list()

seed = 0
scoring = "roc_auc"

cv_results = np.array([])

for name, model in models:
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
        # split the data
        X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index,:].values, X.loc[test_index,:].values
        y_train, y_test = np.ravel(Y[train_index]), np.ravel(Y[test_index])  

        model = model  # Choose a model here
        model.fit(X_train, y_train )  
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

        to_store1.append(train_index)

        # store fold results
        result = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
        cv_results = np.append(cv_results, result)

    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
    cv_results = np.array([])   

# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison-AUC')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried putting `random_state` in all your models?

Comment: yes both of them have a random_state=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you should use `model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]` or `model.decision_function(X_test)` to get identical results since roc auc scorer needs class probabilities. The long answer is that you can reproduce the same behavior with a toy example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer

def assert_equal_scores(rnd_seed, needs_threshold):
    """Assert two different scorings, return equal results."""
    X, y, *_ = load_breast_cancer().values()
    kfold = KFold(random_state=rnd_seed)
    lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=rnd_seed + 10)
    roc_auc_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_threshold=needs_threshold)
    cv_scores1 = cross_val_score(lr, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring=roc_auc_scorer)
    cv_scores2 = cross_val_score(lr, X, y, cv=kfold, scoring='roc_auc')
    np.testing.assert_equal(cv_scores1, cv_scores2)
```

Try `assert_equal_scores(10, False)` and `assert_equal_scores(10, True)` (or any other random seed). The first one raises an `AssertionError`. The difference is that roc auc scorer requires the `needs_threshold` parameter to be `True`.